# Command Line arguments getting added to script path

Tags: python, command-line

I'm doing the exercises from the book 'Automate the Boring Stuff' and have encountered a problem in one of the exercises. I'm trying to write a  program with a .bat file that stores into shelve anything copied on the computers clipboard and assigns it a variable name for future extraction. However, when I input the arguments into the command line, instead of using the arguments, it gives me back an error where it tells me the file does not exist and it adds the arguments tho the path file. I will explain here below:

If I type the following arguments into the command line: `Program.py  save   spam` The command prompt gives me as an error that "file `C:\\Path\Program.pysave" does not exist`

Here is the code to my program, it takes up to three arguments.

```
#! usr/bin/env python
import sys, shelve, pyperclip
Shelf = shelve.open('mcb')

#save whats on the clipboard
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
        print(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])

mcbShelf.close()
```

This is diving me crazy. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what happens when you do `python Program.py  save   spam` to run your script

Comment: it gives me an error that says: "File C:\\Path\Program.pysave" does not exist". Notice how it adds my 'save' argument to the path of the script.

Comment: yes, i see that.so the program doesnt run at all..

Comment: in which path you are running the program?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean? I'm new to programming.

Comment: I figured it out. My .bat file required a 'space' that it did not have. I placed it and it worked. Thank you everyone for the help.